# Problems with extruded curve and solidify modifier

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, 3d-printing, extrude

I'm relatively new to blender and am having issues with a curve that has a solidify modifier applied to it. I'm trying to 3d print cookie cutters and need to take custom curves, extrude them to a specific height, then give them a thickness, like 1-2mm. I've configured blender to use mm as my unit of measurement and everything seems to be okay. However, when curves are too sharp, as shown, they get these weird overlaps which end up becoming holes in my print.

Image of curve  with weird artifacts:
https://cl.ly/a5cf7eadb762

My solidify settings: 
https://cl.ly/b12de88a42ab

The geometry settings: 
https://cl.ly/ad8a526e4f17

What it looks like when I bring the exported .stl into tinkercad (for example): https://cl.ly/c4cf484e2872

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please place all your images in the question itself.  You may use free GIMP or the image editor of your choice to do this.  Please do this in the future as well. The user need not click to a different website for a simple image.  It shows more effort on your part.  It is tedious to click on these four links.

Answer (score 1):

It seems logic that if your angle is very sharp, your *Solidify* modifier may create a problem, because the thickness profile can easily overlap itself. So I guess what you have to do is either change the *Thickness* to a negative value (in your case), or convert your curve to mesh and bring some corrections manually.

[image]